# IIF false expression impacting truthiness?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am developing an SSRS tablix report and struggling to remove some error messages from certain cells. The Expression in the cell is as follows:

`=Iif(IsNothing(First(Fields!Details.Value)) , "", Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!studyTitle.Value, Fields!studyTitle.Value, Fields!Link.Value ,"DataSet1")), vbCrLf ))`

The custom function that's referenced is as follows:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object())  As String()
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
Continue For
End If
items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
Return unique
End Function
```

The problem I'm encountering is that cells in the output will display "#ERROR" if they are being run through the custom function with multiple blank values.

The goal of the initial IIF statement is to test those rows first to make sure that the function is only applied to those rows that have values, and the other cells should just be blank. The problem is that I'm still seeing errors for those cells, as if the false condition is applied anyway.

However, if I edit my IIF statement to have the same test condition but different true-part and false-part i.e.:

```
Iif(IsNothing(First(Details.Value)), "true", "false"))
```

Then suddenly I see exactly the rows I would expect to see marked true and false. If this is the case then I can't figure out where the errors are coming from in my initial statement.

I know the issue has to be somewhere with the RemoveDuplicates function because when I take that part out and just Join my duplicated values then I see no errors, and the false rows are the same as identified above.

Does anyone see something I'm missing that is generating this error or causing this seemingly inconsistent behavior from the IIf function?

Comment: SSRS conditionals do not adhere to short-circuit boolean evaluation and therefore the right-hand side argument is being evaluated before the comparison is made. You may have to guard against nulls in your function calls.

Comment: I don't think you need the **JOIN** - your function is already returning the data as a string. Not sure if that's the error though. Doesn't hurt to try removing it (and the `, VBCRLF`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `If` instead of `IIf`. The `If` construct shortcuts the evaluation, while the `IIf` evaluates all expressions.

```
=If(IsNothing(First(Fields!Details.Value)) , "", Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!studyTitle.Value, Fields!studyTitle.Value, Fields!Link.Value ,"DataSet1")), vbCrLf ))
```

This is only available in VB.net and is not available in VBA. In VBA, you would use a standard `If-Then-Else` construct.